# Usage of "used to + verb" versus "would + verb"

Tags: used-to

I was trying to translate a sentence into English the other day and was wondering what is the best way to put it.

In the sentence the speaker is telling that **he had been on another opinion in the the first place but now he thought differently**. I thought of three different ways of saying this, and am wondering if these three sentences mean the same? I also think that, **at first** is redundant in the third sentence.

1. **Oh, I would thought the same!**
2. **Oh, I used to think the same!**
3. **Oh, I used to think the same at first!**

Comment: You can say *As a teenager, I **would visit** my grandmother every Sunday* OR *...I **used to** visit...*, where both are perfectly idiomatic and mean exactly the same. BUT whereas you can say *Until I met you I **used to think** girls were soppy*, you CAN'T idiomatically say *Until I met you I **would think** girls were soppy*. I'm not sure exactly how to "explain" that difference, but the long and short of it is your first option is syntactically completely invalid with past tense ***thought***, but even if we change it to the syntactically "valid" ***think***, it's still not idiomatic.

Comment: Note that ***at first*** isn't necessarily completely redundant. You *might* be a pensioner talking about how you thought girls were "soppy" in your first term as a 13-year-old at a mixed-sex school - but by the second term (and for the rest of your life), you might have decided girls were "interesting". The ***at first*** there is a useful way of emphasising that you only had that negative opinion ***for a relatively short initial period***. But whatever the exact contextual meaning, ***at first*** implies you changed your opinion ***some time ago*** (not within this conversation).

Comment: Do you mean *would have thought* in your first sentence? (If so, that's a bit different than *used to think*, but I don't want to just assume that for the answer)

Comment: So if I omit "would" and just say "I thought so at first" or "I used to think so at first" , both are correct? and both implies a same meaning? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @MaciejStachowski. What if I say "I had thought like you at first, but now have a different opinion" ? would it work?

Comment: *had thought* isn't ungrammatical, though it feels a bit off - Past Perfect is mostly used to refer to something before a certain point in the past (eg. *I **had thought** so until I **met** John*), so it feels like you want to put focus on some event in the past that made you stop thinking so, but it's missing from the sentence. *used to* puts more importance on the fact that you don't think so *now*.